# Another recursive definition question

Tags: functions

http://vvcap.net/db/vPo_GbDDwvkN3_ASoW6g.htp

I have tried multiples definitions but can't seem to get the correct one
Subfive(0)= 5
Subfive(x)= 250-subfive(x-1)-5

subfive(1)=250-5-5 which is obviously wrong...

subfive(x)= 250-subfive(x-1)

subfive(0) = 5
subfive(1)= 250-subfive(0)
subfive(2)=250-subfive(1)

again, wrong..

Comment: Try this: each $subFive$ is the previous $subFive$ minus 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to look at is what the first term is, and what the rate of change is. In this case, the first term is 250, and the rate of change is -5. Therefore, the previous function is five numbers higher than the current one. Taking the first term, the complete recursive function would be the following:

f(0) = 250, f(x) = f(x-1) - 5

If you want the explicit, this is what it would be:

f(x) = 250 - 5x

Always remember to figure out the first term, and the rate of change when finding a recursive function. This will make it much easier for you to figure out function like this.

Comment: that helped a lot actually, ill be posting more recursion questions throughout the night so keep looking out please  :P

Comment: Ok, I'll be sure to look for them. Studying for an algebra exam?

Comment: Studying Computer Science, but we have a big Maths exam coming up : )